# Use Jquery to sort wordpress posts on a page by custom numeric value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, sorting

So I have this plugin, http://codecanyon.net/item/taxonomies-filter-widget/full_screen_preview/4282257 that basically filters posts (in my case).

I have used the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields", documentation here: http://advancedcustomfields.com/resources/
I used this to add a number field to my create post form. Basically, it is a field to enter the price.

I'm interested in using JS to order the posts on a page (that has been filtered, using the plugin) in ascending and descending orders based on the price. Not sure how I can do this since the documentation for "Advanced Custom Fields" only talks about php.

Is there an easy way of using only JS to do what I want? 
I hope I was clear

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could show us more of your implementation?
Take a look at http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/
I think it is what you need!

Comment: Right after I posted I found that plugin! I use php to get the values and I insert the values into the html. So this plugin would be able to target the html of each post (since they all have the same structure) and sort it, right?

Comment: Yeah you are right. You can sort stuff on the user-side which means you can sort stuff that is already present in the DOM/HTML.
You will build the entire page with PHP and then the client-side JS will take care of this last sorting.